# Parameter not getting passed in AJAX call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am using the following code

```
function test()
{
   GetAttributesForSelectedControlType('Phone Number');
}

function GetAttributesForSelectedControlType(questionType) {
    alert(questionType);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Wizards/GetAttributesForSelectedControlType/' + questionType,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success');
        }

    });
}
```

PLEASE NOTE: QUESTIONTYPE is a STRING value and not any type..

The issue is that in the controller, I m getting a hit on `"GetAttributesForSelectedControlType"` function but the parameter value is coming null.
I am sending string in `questionType`.
any ideas on this?

Comment: Are you getting correct value in alert?

Comment: Show us the code from where you are passing the parameter i.e. how you are calling the function.

Comment: @Amit Yes the value in alert is exactly what i need.

Comment: Also, the method-signature/route-setup might help.

Comment: Use this as querystring. then you will get value

Comment: @MicrosoftPS the question is tagged .net and mvc (which probably means ASP.NET MVC), in which case he doesn't call the method himself, the framework does.

Comment: Can you try as I told previously

Comment: @Gautam - One 'Hit&Try' suggestion. In your controller change the parameter to id. E.g `public ReturnType GetAttributesForSelectedControlType (string id){}`

Comment: @Gautam, show the controller signature and also any route if you have defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function GetAttributesForSelectedControlType(questionType) {
    alert(questionType);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Wizards/GetAttributesForSelectedControlType',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: {
            questionType: questionType
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to pass question type as an argument you should use `data:{qType:questionType}` this will fill the argument qType of the function `GetAttributesForSelectedControlType`

Comment: it does not matter if it is a simple string or another object. Ideally with what you are doing you should not even hit the controller with what you are doing, if questionType has any value. Any of the solutions posted above is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function GetAttributesForSelectedControlType(questionType) {

    $.get('/Wizards/GetAttributesForSelectedControlType', {questionType: questionType })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert('success');
    });

}
```

You need to pass in `questionType` as a data. Alternatively you could just add the follwoing into your existing ajax call.

```
data: {questionType: questionType }
```

This will work with the following action:

```
public ActionResult GetAttributesForSelectedControlType(string questionType)
{
    // ...

}
```